# May I have into account security concerns when considering to send emails massively (>100,000)?

Tags: email

I'm considering sending more than 100,000 emails as fast as possible to different users of my website. These is not spam but requested emails. I'm using my own mail server (Exchange 2010).

May I have into account any security concerns?

For example, I think that:

- My IPs may be blacklisted by remote mail servers (if for example I
  send too much emails to Gmail receivers...)
- An attacker may see that I am sending lots of emails and try to phish my customers

Any other security concerns?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: Your second point, about phishing, is not relevant to the problem you are asking about (even using MSExchange). But, of course that does not mean you shouldn't take appropriate measures to protect your data and prevent your service from being spoofed.

Comment: Your question about Phishing is quite a different subject. You can post a new question with more context for this.

Comment: Isn't your main question about Email Sending Reputation? That's not really a Security issue per se, so you might want to tweak the wording there.

Comment: @symcbean I don't think that my customers may be phised easily if I send massively emails a "different subject". Not differentiating between genuine and fake emails is a security concern in my opinion...

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I think not being able to send emails to a user because my mail server has been blacklisted is some kind of "availability" and thus a security concern...I see that I'm not talked of being hacked but when talking about confidentiality, integrity, availability, trazability and non-repuditation I see security there. May be this is a more philosophical question than techcnical: "what is and what is not infosec?"

Comment: @EloyRoldánParedes *"if I send massively emails a 'different subject'"* This appears to be incomprehensible. Can you please rephrase? *"Not differentiating between genuine and fake emails"* It is hard to understand what you mean specifically.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Sorry, what I mean is that I think that phising and bad email reputation are security concerns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905805

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail receivers often track sender spam **reputation per IP address**. If you use a **third-party** provider to send the emails, then it is their IP which will take the reputation hit not yours. This is important to understand, as you **don't** want your all-important company Email Server to be on the same IP that sends a questionable quantity of emails.

Make sure that your email server is properly configured with a correct **rDNS** entry set up by your ISP. Also you should keep proper **SPF** records up to date.

You should **throttle** your emails. Sending them 'as fast as possible' will surely get you banned. It is much safer to spread them out with a delay between emails.

It is likely that your email traffic will have to go up **gradually**, or perhaps you will have to fill out unblock requests from the big carriers (Microsoft, AT&T, etc) as they will not take kindly to the huge spike in traffic (assuming this IP sends only minimal traffic prior to this)

You can also list an official **unsubscribe** feature, so that the mail client (i.e. Gmail) can provide a simple Unsubscribe quick link.

If you send enough email from your domain, Gmail will provide you with reporting on how well your emails fair.

There must be some canonical answer to how to properly **format** emails to avoid spam marks, but I'm not sure where it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905805

Answer (score 2):

If you do not implement proper rate limiting, your mail server's IP Address could get blacklisted and all mail rejected.

**Good Practices:**

- Only send a few emails per second (do not send 1000s emails in 3 seconds).
- Use proper SPF records.
- DKIM sign all messages.
- Include an unsubscribe link as to comply with the "CAN-SPAM" act.

If you get blacklisted and you have a provider  with bad policies they could choose to terminate your account for spamming, this would include accidentally getting the IP blacklisted. Good luck with your project and I hope these key points help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google and other well known mailing system would blacklist your IP, and your your mail server IP would land up in the spammers list (https://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/) even if you are using it for legitimate purpose.

Another point to consider is to make sure you have the SPF record for your domain or google mail drop all your mails.